# Not getting any response from smtp server

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to sent a mail through following java code.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.host",mailProperties.get("mail.smtp"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
     final PasswordAuthentication pauth;
    pauth = new PasswordAuthentication(""+mailProperties.get("mail.user"),""+mailProperties.get("mail.pwd"));

   class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
        {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return pauth;
            }

        }


        Authenticator auth = new MyAuthenticator();
            Session mail = Session.getInstance(props,auth);
        mail.setDebug(true);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mail);
            Transport.send(msg);
```

But not being able to send mail, 
only output I am getting is as follows :

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG: SMTPTransport trying to connect to host "mail.bizsolindia.com", port 465
```

[image]

While trying to check with telnet I am getting the response as shown in screen shot.

Kindly suggest any correction required from my side.

Comment: Most likely you have a firewall or antivirus that's preventing you from connecting.  The JavaMail FAQ has more [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug) as well as information on how to [connect through a proxy server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to connect to the server?

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It was antivirus blocking my connection. Now I am getting 220 reply while trying connection with TELNET. But further to that now I am getting error as "DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [LO2P265CA0227.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

DEBUG SMTP SENT: QUIT"  Can you help with this?